Activating smooth muscle tissue with electrical field
I see applying 20 mV to the smooth cell cell will make it contract/ relax, I wonder will it contract/ relax if i apply the same amount to a strip of tissue (I am asking this because people of applying 20V, 40V in organ bath type studies to intestine tissue while modeling studies involving Hai-Murphy type model use -70 mV as resting potential and -30-40mV as activation potential, doesn't that mean the rest of the voltage is an overkill?). Thank you!

20V or 40V over a bath isn't the same as that voltage over a membrane. Think from the perspective of some cell's membrane: what voltage is that membrane actually "seeing"?
